# How many XML tree(parent children) can create in Java Marshalling and Unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jax-rs, marshalling, unmarshalling

I want to create a XML file using java Marshalling and Unmarshalling. How to develop Java class get following Type XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<vxml version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml 
 http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/vxml.xsd">
  <form>
    <grammar src="cityandstate.grxml" type="application/srgs+xml"/>
    <block>
      <prompt bargein="false">
        <audio src="http://localhost.com/obl.wav"/>
      </prompt>
    </block>
  </from>
</vxml>
```

I want to get like this XML in Jax-Rs web service there are using Hibernate, Spring and Maven. this class want to run through Jax-Rx web service.

Comment: I try [ link ](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jaxb-tutorial-getting-started.html ). get  answer but I get only two children in that scenario. why this hapen to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an XSD available you can use the [JAXB2 Maven Plugin](https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home) to generate the appropriate types for you.

You can do so by adding the following to your pom.xml:

```
<project ...>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

It will try to find your XSD files and optional binding configuration in `src/main/resources`. If your XSD references other XSD files (as in the question), these referred files also need to be present in the same directory.

Comment: I try to this way but I can't get last child details only.

Comment: Without seeing what you exactly tried it's hard to say what is going wrong.

Comment: below type XML want to get as my output in Jax-rs web service, There want use **Marshalling** and **Unmarshalling**